# error when registering a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

"invalid nib registered for identifier (myGoal) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance"

Thats the exception I keep on getting.  I am using both, storyboard and XIB.

In my storyboard, I have a tableview inside of a navigation view. The tableview is set to dynamic prototypes and the number of prototype cells is zero.  The reason is because I wanted to add a custom cell programmatically.

The first time I added the cells programmatically, I was using one of the generic cell styles.  At it would work!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myGoal"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myGoal"
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //do stuff with cell
}
```

It would let me have a tableview with the default cell style, which has one label.

Next I wanted to customize my cell so that it would have multiple label and a few extra buttons.  Normally, I'd do it in a storyboard interface builder, but this time I need to do it programatically.

So I created a custom tableviewcell class along with its Xib counterpart.  In the Xib I designed it how I wanted.  The problem is in getting this cell to show up in the tableview.

Does it matter that the tableview is in a storyboard and the tableviewcell is in a xib?

In order to register the custom nib, I did almost the same thing as above, yet it crashes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *dhCustomNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DHTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:dhCustomNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myGoal"];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DHTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myGoal"
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath]; //It crashes at this point
    //do stuff with cell
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show how your nib is set up? You need to ensure that there is one top level object and it needs to have it's class set to be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Your `DHTableViewCell` class should be a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and must be the only top level object in the nib

Comment: If you have any gesture recognisers set up the nib , they will cause this error.

Comment: @Paul.s Files owner is set to DHTableViewCell.  How do I set it so that there is only one top level object?

Comment: @Paul.s DHTableViewCell is already set as a subclass to uitableviewcell.  In the xib's identity inspector, the custom class is already set to DHTableViewCell.  I'm not sure what else I am missing.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I have no gesture recognisers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the top level object as the `DHTableViewCell` subclass not the file's owner.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  Well apparently I had a table view cell and there was a label that existed behind the table view cell.  I did not notice it.  on the side bar it shows table view cell a line below it and then an instance of a label.  Upon deleting the label, the exception stopped occurring.

I suppose this means I had 2 top level objects, a tableview and a label.

However, I do not understand how the mire existence of another label would cause so much trouble.  Also, why is it even allowed, if you are not allowed?

Comment: In general it's not illegal to have more than one top level object in nibs. It's Apple's class so you have to play by their rules - it could be a performance optimisation as you want the objects to load as quickly as possible or it could just be an arbitrary requirement - who knows...